# Wordpress author box

Tags: author

I have a wordpress site which on media temple shared hosting. When my site on shared hosting, wordpress author box does not appear. I have transfered my site from shared hosting to my server. After I transfered my site, double author box appear on my blogs pages. All codes are same. What is the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: Where's the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Gameleon theme. Single.php code line between 224-261:

```
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="pagination">' . __( 'Pages:', 'gameleon' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

</div><?php // end of .post-entry / ?>
</div><?php // end of #post-the_ID(); / ?>

</div><?php // end of td-wrap-content / ?>
</div><?php // end of td-content-inner / ?>



<?php  if( !function_exists( 'wpsabox_author_box' ) and get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) != '' and gameleon_get_option(     'td_post_author_box' ) == 1 ) : ?>

<div class="td-content-inner-single">

<div id="author-meta">
<?php if( function_exists( 'get_avatar' ) ) {
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), '100' );
} ?>
<div class="about-author"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div>
<div class="auth-desc vcard author"><span class="fn"><?php     the_author_meta( 'description' ) ?></span></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div><?php // end of #author-meta / ?>

</div><?php // end of td-content-inner-single / ?>

<?php endif; // no description, no author's meta ?>


<?php if ( function_exists( 'wpsabox_author_box' ) ) :?>
<div class="td-content-inner-single-sabox">
<?php echo wpsabox_author_box(); // Our Simple Author Box plugin ?>
</div><?php // end of td-content-inner-single-sabox / ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php echo gameleon_related_posts(); ?>
```

I removed,    "php echo wpsabox_author_box(); // Our Simple Author Box plugin ?>" but, this only removed one author box, other author box still appear on site.

Comment: You should add this as an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/198116/edit) to your question above, not as an answer.